# How can I write one after another JSON data

Tags: json, go

I am working on a website **scraper**. I can send only 1 JSON data to JSON file regularly. I want to write **one after another** JSON data, so I need to keep hundreds of data in a single JSON file. like this

```
[
 {
  "id": 1321931,
  "name": "Mike"
 },
 {
    "id": 32139219,
    "name": "Melissa"
 },
 {
    "id": 8421921,
    "name": "Jordan"
 },
 {
    "id": 4291901,
    "name": "David"
 }
]
```

but output like this. When I send new data, **just the first JSON data update itself**.

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Mike"
 }
]
```

here is the code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

type Info struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

var tpl *template.Template
var name string
var stonf Info
var allInfos []Info
var id int

var co = colly.NewCollector()

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Started...")
    allInfos = make([]Info, 1)

    id = rand.Intn((99999 - 10000) + 10000)

    // Reading Data From Json
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("stocky.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR 1 JSON", err)
    }
    // Unmarshal JSON data
    var d []Info
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &d)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    tpl, _ = tpl.ParseGlob("templates/*.html")
    http.HandleFunc("/mete", hellloHandleFunc)
    staticHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css/"))
    http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css", staticHandler))
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil)
}

func hellloHandleFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    allInfos[0].ID = id // JSON-PRO

    // GET Price - Fiyat GETİR
    co.OnHTML("div#dp", func(p *colly.HTMLElement) {
        name = p.ChildText("h1#title")
    })
    requestLink := strings.TrimSpace(r.FormValue("input-link"))

    co.Visit(requestLink)

    // FIRST DATA JSON
    enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    enc.SetIndent("", " ")
    enc.Encode(allInfos)

    stonf = Info{
        Name: name,
    }

    fmt.Println("Index Running")
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "form-copy.html", stonf)
}

func writeJson(data []Info) {
    dataFile, err := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", " ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Could not create JSON", err)
    }

    ioutil.WriteFile("stocky.json", dataFile, 0666)
}
```

Comment: Am i correctly understand that the code should do following things:
-> On init read `stocky.json`. 
-> After receiving the request should scrap url provided in a request and extract name
-> After scrapping should output current value to Stdout.

So, when `writeJson` you expect to be invoked? What is the role of the id variable?
In general you should have something like this
```
currentInfo = Info{ID: id, name: name}
allInfos = append(allInfos, currentInfo)
```
in you request handler.

Comment: Yes, almost correct. id variable is random. there is stonf = Info{ID:id, Name: name, }. When I click submit button on HTML, writeJSON expect to be invoked

Comment: @Melisa Could you simplify the code? All the handler stuff doesn't look pertinent to the problem you're facing. Reducing your code to a minimal example could even put you on the path to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which appends new `Info` to the list and store in file.
The solution will perform properly only for relatively small list. For large lists, the overhead of writing the entire file each time may be too high. In such case i propose to change the format to [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/). It will allow to write only the current `Info` struct instead of the whole list.
I've also added synchronization mechanism to avoid race conditions in case you send multiple HTTP requests at the same time.

I assumed that the identifier must be generated separately for each request, and it is not a problem if collision occur.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

type (
    Info struct {
        ID   int    `json:"id"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }
    Infos struct {
        List []Info
        sync.Mutex
    }
)

var (
    infos *Infos
    tpl *template.Template
    co = colly.NewCollector()
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Started...")

    var err error
    infos, err = readInfos()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tpl, _ = tpl.ParseGlob("templates/*.html")
    http.HandleFunc("/mete", hellloHandleFunc)
    staticHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css/"))
    http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css", staticHandler))
    if err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func hellloHandleFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    stonf := Info{
        ID: rand.Intn((99999 - 10000) + 10000),
    }
    // GET Price - Fiyat GETİR
    co.OnHTML("div#dp", func(p *colly.HTMLElement) {
        stonf.Name = p.ChildText("h1#title")
    })
    requestLink := strings.TrimSpace(r.FormValue("input-link"))

    if err := co.Visit(requestLink); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := infos.AppendAndWrite(stonf); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // FIRST DATA JSON
    enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    enc.SetIndent("", " ")
    enc.Encode(stonf)

    fmt.Println("Index Running")
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "form-copy.html", stonf)
}

func readInfos() (*Infos, error) {
    // Reading Data From Json
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("stocky.json")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var r []Info
    // Unmarshal JSON data
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Infos{List: r}, nil
}

func (i *Infos) AppendAndWrite(info Info) error {
    i.Lock()
    defer i.Unlock()
    i.List = append(i.List, info)
    if err := i.storeLocked(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("storing info list failed: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func (i *Infos) storeLocked() error {
    dataFile, err := json.MarshalIndent(i.List, "", " ")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not marshal infos JSON: %w", err)
    }
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("stocky.json", dataFile, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not write 'stocky.json' file: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard called JSON lines (https://jsonlines.org/) consisting on only one JSON per line instead of wrapping all in a JSON array.
JSON library from Go stdlib works pretty well with JSON lines on both cases, reading and writing.

Write multiple JSON (one per line):

```
e := json.NewEncoder(yourWriterFile)
e.Encode(object1)
e.Encode(object2)
//...
```

Read multiple JSON (one per line or concatenated):

```
d := json.NewDecoder(yourReaderFile)
d.Decode(&object1)
d.Decode(&object2)
//...
```

More info: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json